# Octave error: Invalid character

Tags: octave, matlab

I get the following error running Octave on Mac:

```
octave:29> inputFile("test.txt")
error: invalid character '?' (ASCII 226) near line 3, column 8
parse error near line 3 of file [filepath]/inputFile.m

  syntax error

>>>     A = {”<Start>”};    
          ^
```

The m-file looks as follows:

```
function A = inputFile (filename)

A = {”<Start>”};    

file = fopen(filename);

while (!feof(file)) 
        line = fgetl(file);
        A = {A ; strsplit(line) ; ”<Radbrytning>”};
    endwhile

    fclose(file);

    A = {A ; ”<Stop>"}

endfunction
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'` or `"` but not `”` for string constants. I would recommend the first for compatibility with matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar issues when copy+pasting matrices or equations out of PDF's. It leads to extremely difficult-to-find evil hidden characters that often your text editor will fail to clue you in on. Sublime Text can be pretty smart about it, but when I was using Vim for example (with matlab filetype) it just ignores these characters. Then Octave will choke on it.